# Merging MovieClips into a larger MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3

I have these 2 separate FLA (AS3) files and I want to merge them together. One FLA, let's name "Animation.fla", consists of a 1-frame animation with a class assigned to its main stage, let's label it "MainStage.cs." The other FLA file, label it, "Navigator.fla", consists of 3 frames where I have to navigate different frames to get to the animation on the Animation.fla.

I have tried nesting the two  but I gain errors when trying to convert the whole Animation.fla to movieclip and put it on the frame of the Navigator.fla. It's seems it's not the correct way to do it.

Please fill me in with ideas on merging animations with Classes since I'm still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried nesting the two but I
>   gain errors when trying to convert the
>   whole Animation.fla to movieclip and
>   put it on the frame of the
>   Navigator.fla. It's seems it's not the
>   correct way to do it.

This is one way to do it. It could be that your code has errors. Please post your code.

In the meantime, check if:
-your MovieClips have instance names
-you are referencing your MovieClips correctly in your code.

Comment: My codes do not have errors other than errors I gain when merging the two. Thanks for the reply and suggestions but I have already found a way of merging the two without affecting each other. I tried using swf variables between two different flash objects playing and it works fine for me.


I will check about referencing my movie clips correctly so that I will also be able to learn how to really merge them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could you create a new movieclip on the stage of Animation.fla and select all of the frames in Navigator.fla, right click and "copy frames".  Then go back to Animation.fla and paste them into your new movieclip.
  This will work if you don't have a main class in Animation.fla.

Comment: That's the thing. I have a main class in Animation.fla.